# Write a javascript function that checks whether an element is in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, function

When i run this function I get a syntax error unexpected number

```
    var numberList = [1, 5, 2, 20, 7, 90, 3];
    function inArray( numberList, 90 ) {
        for (var i = 0; i < numberList.length; i++) {
            if(numberlist[i] === 90){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
        }
        }
    }
    inArray();
```

Comment: `numberList.includes(90)` seems easier :)

Comment: `var 90 = 80` give me the same error :( - (You need to declare parameters and pass them to  the function BTW)

Comment: Sorry im new to javascript, could you be more specific how that would look and work in the code block?

Comment: `function inArray( arr, findMe ) { .... }`  and then > `inArray(numberList, 90);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting confused between method declaration and method invocation. 
When you define a function you declare the arguments which the function expects, and you can use whatever name you want there, because that name is just a reference inside the function body to the parameter that you will pass when you invoke the function.

So in your case:

```
var numberList = [1, 5, 2, 20, 7, 90, 3];
    // function declaration
    function inArray( myList, numberToFind) {
        for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
            if(myList[i] === numberToFind){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
        }
        }
    }
    // function invocation 
    inArray(numberList, 90);
```

Then when you are performing a check, you can directly return the check instead of using if and returning true false.

Moreover, your script checks only the first number and then returns immediately true or false.

So your function should look like this:

```js
function inArray( myList, numberToFind ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
        if(myList[i] === numberToFind){
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
var array = [1, 3, 5, 6];
console.log(inArray(array, 5));
```

I guess that this is only an experiment because for finding an element inside an array JavaScript already provides several ways :)

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You need only to return `true` in the loop, if found, because you need to visit all items if not found.

Then I suggest to use a parameter for number to search for.

```js
function inArray(array, value) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var numberList = [1, 5, 2, 20, 7, 90, 3];

console.log(inArray(numberList, 90));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are implementing this to learn about JavaScript.  Otherwise you would just use something like `numberList.includes(90)` and be done.

When you define a function, the parameters you send to the function are not literal values (like `90`).  Instead they are variables that are active in the scope of the function:

```
function inArray( arr, number ) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i] === number){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then, when you call a function, you pass the *actual* values:

```
inArray(numberList, 90);
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped me so much to understand how the function works! The only issue I have now is its not returning anything back to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could use array.indexOf(element) to check if an element is contained within the array.

It returns -1 if the element is not in the array, or the position of the array that the element is.

So basicly if it returns >= 0, then the array contains the element.

=== extra ====

In addition to Davin Tryon answer, if you are having difficulties to understand function parameters, I recommend you to search for the differences between argumens and parameters.

Comment: Yes they can, but you didn't address the issue in their code